# Laravel left join showing error on 'ON' multiple condition

Tags: laravel

When i tried using left join in laravel I am getting below error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$dat' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `students`.`id`, `students`.`name`, `attendance_student`.`date` from `students` left join `attendance_student` on `students`.`id` = `attendance_student`.`student_id` and `attendance_student`.`date` = `$dat`)

Basically I am trying to get attendance of all students on a particular date

My Code:

```
$dat = 2015-10-15;
    $student = DB::table('students')
            ->leftJoin('attendance_student', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('students.id', '=', 'attendance_student.student_id');
                $join->on('attendance_student.date', '=', $dat);
            })

            ->select('students.id', 'students.name', 'attendance_student.date'
                )
            ->get();
```

PLease help

Answer (score 0):

**Your issue:** Variable scopes

**Solution:**

```
$dat = 2015-10-15;
$student = DB::table('students')
        ->leftJoin('attendance_student', function($join) use ($dat)
        {
            $join->on('students.id', '=', 'attendance_student.student_id');
            $join->on('attendance_student.date', '=', $dat);
        })

        ->select('students.id', 'students.name', 'attendance_student.date'
            )
        ->get();
```

**Explanation:**

When accessing variables that were declared outside the scope of the lambda function (the `function($join)` one), make use of `use` statement to allow access to those variables inside the function.

**Source:** http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php